# ElevationScroll 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactElement<any, string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to implement https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#elevate-app-bar into my app as the following:

```
interface Props {
    children: React.ReactElement;
}

export const ElevationScroll = ({children}: Props) => {

    const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
        disableHysteresis: true,
        threshold: 0
    });

    return React.cloneElement(children, {
        elevation: trigger ? 4 : 0,
    });
}
```

and here how do I use the `ElevationScroll` component:

```
return (
        <div className={classes.grow}>
            <CssBaseline/>
            <ElevationScroll>
                <AppBar position="static" style={{backgroundColor: "#880e4f"}}>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <IconButton
                            edge="start"
                            className={classes.menuButton}
                            color="inherit"
                            aria-label="open drawer"
                        >
                            <MenuIcon/>
......
```

The compiler complains:

```
This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>', but multiple children were provided.
```

I know that `prop children` is missing but I do not know how to pass children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with:

```js
import {ReactElement} from 'react'

export default ComponentWithChildren {
      children: ReactElement | ReactElement []
}
```

That is, the component will receive a ReactElement or several ReactElements. If your component will receive multiple children, do the following:

```js
ComponentWithChildren {
  children: ReactElement []
}
```

Comment: Where is your final code? is this replacing the code for the scrolling component